# consolidating the json reports in postman-newman

Tags: postman, newman, postman-newman

please help me! Now I have faced with an issue, when we run multiple collections with Newman, there will be HTML or JSON reports for each collection and I want to have a single consolidated JSON report like merging all JSON reports of all collections into one. Is there any way of doing it for Newman?